# What software is used to create these sort of icons?

Tags: icon, software-recommendation

[image]

[image]

I've seen these icons in several sites which have a sample of some business diagrams.

It seems that they're all using the same software to create those diagrams, I wonder what the software is?

Comment: try saving the icons from your browser context menu and then looking inside with a text or hex editor. for certain file formats you might get lucky and find some clues to tools or versions, svg for example and a lot of meta-data can be kept inside jpegs

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell which software was used. It could have quite literally been any number of image editing applications, including raster or vector image editors, or even 3d modelling applications.